# Django denormalization and consistency

Tags: django

I'm not sure how to do denormalization in Django. As per me I'm thinking of doing something like this:

I have 2 models:

Category:

```
 name = m.CharField(max_length = 127)
```

Articles:

```
 name = m.CharField(max_length = 127)
 category = m.ForeignKey(Category)
 category_name = m.CharField(max_length = 127)
```

I would like this to happen:

When I change the name of any category to reflect changes in all articles. Now, what is really the best practice when we don't have only one or 2 fields but around 10-20 to keep in sync?

Comment: This seems like an odd case for denormalization. Why do you think you need it? Are you sure you have a bottleneck in getting the category information?

Comment: If I would have to show up a list of articles with their brand I would need to make an Inner Join. In this case I would not need any join...

Comment: That's obviously true, but what is wrong with a join? Databases are good at those. Denormalization is only necessary if you've determined you definitely have a performance problem at that point.

Comment: I would not want to have any joins in simple queries like this that will be made thousand of times...

Answer (score 7):

I **recommend** using relations and denormalizing **only** if you have performance issues and **only** after you confirmed that this bad performance is related to querying the category name. Otherwise it's just adding complexity without a good reason. Keep in mind [Donald Knuth's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) famous quote:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Relational databases are good at joins, because basically that's what they were designed for. In the denormalized design you want, instead of the simplest possible `JOINs` you will need complex `UPDATEs`. These updates will affect many rows in many (10-20) tables. If you have lot of data in affected tables and often change the category_name it could/will even make the performance worse.

---

If you're really stuck with the idea of `category_name` in 10-20 tables consider using a [database trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger). Trigger will be executed when a category table is changed. It can handle all of the updates internally in the database. Without changing anything in your Django project and with less overhead.

So if you're really stuck with the idea of  `category_name` in 10-20 tables and you **can't** use triggers there's a mechanism called [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) in Django. These are kind of triggers embedded into Django and fired before/after defined event.

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.core.exceptions import DatabaseError

class Category(m.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Category, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Store the initial name
        self._name = self.name

    name = m.CharField(max_length = 127)

def update_category_name(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """ Callback executed when Category is about to be saved """

    old_category = instance._name
    new_category = instance.name

    if old_category != new_category:     # Name changed

        # Start a transaction ?

        try:
            # Update the data:

            # Make category_name an db_index, otherwise it will be slooooooooow
            Article.objects.filter(category_name=old_category).update(category_name=new_category) 

            # commit transaction ?

        except DatabaseError as e: 
            # rollback transaction ?
            # prevent saving the category as database will be inconsistent

            raise e

# Bind the callback to pre_save singal
signals.pre_save.connect(update_category_name, sender=Category)
```